# Apply Symbology to Layer not working outside of ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

I am running ArcGIS 10.2.2 Version 10.2.2.3552, using ArcMap.

I am creating a python script and one of the things i need to do is apply symbology from layer to a shapefile in my mxd that is maintained outside of the mxd.  It works fine in model builder but when i run it in python i get multiple errors.

Code:

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy


# Local variables:
Tioga = "Tioga\\Tioga"
Tioga_lyr = "C:\\Users\\jcarl\\Desktop\\Dynamic LH Map\\Symbology\\Tioga.lyr"

# Process: Apply Symbology From Layer
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(Tioga, Tioga_lyr)
```

[image: Model]

Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 10, in    File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6004, in ApplySymbologyFromLayer     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000966: The input layer is not valid Failed to execute (ApplySymbologyFromLayer).

Comment: Are you running this in the python window within ArcMap?

Comment: Yes.  My main goal is to run outside of arcmap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I realized my first answer was incorrect, this is an update (I forgot that the function needs a Layer object, not a dataset path).

I think the issue is that the you are passing "Tioga\Tioga" (which is a technically a string) but the Apply Symbology function needs a Layer object.  You can create the layer object like this:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
Tioga = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"Tioga1")[0]

arcpy.management.ApplySymbologyFromLayer(Tioga,symbologylayerpath)
```

Before trying this, rename your layer "Tioga1" in the table of contents, otherwise it'll grab the group layer and not work.

Apologies for the misdirection earlier.

Comment: This is the way to go. To run it outside ArcMap, simply change the mxd variable: `mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\gis\mymap.mxd")`

Comment: Can somebody tell me the difference from ApplySymbology and Update symbology?  Do they accomplish the same task, or when is a situation when i would use update opposed to apply?

Comment: Hmm, I've never used update layer before, but it looks like it'll pull more info over, like a definition query and alias.  I wouldn't expect that there's any difference between using Update Layer with symbology_only=True and using Apply Symbology From Layer.

Comment: ok, apply layer from symbology seems to be working great so I'm not going to mess with a good thing!